# SQL Server XML parse issue

Tags: sql-server, xml

I need to parse XML into a SQL Server 2012 database. However, I cannot find any good guide to parse this kind XML (here is SELECT TOP 2 FROM table):

```
<ns2:SoftWare xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example2.com"><keyc>123-ABC</keyc><statusc>Y</statusc></ns2:SoftWare>
<ns2:custom-data xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/2"><timec>2016.01.02</timec><customer>8R</customer><keyc>8R</keyc><statusc>N</statusc></ns2:custom-data>
```

Any help, how I can parse "keyc" value from XML?

So, I can use it select clause / or insert it to database.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `nodes` and `value` to get that entity:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (XmlText XML)
INSERT @Data VALUES
    ('<ns2:SoftWare xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example2.com"><keyc>123-ABC</keyc><statusc>Y</statusc></ns2:SoftWare>'),
    ('<ns2:custom-data xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/2"><timec>2016.01.02</timec><customer>8R</customer><keyc>8R</keyc><statusc>N</statusc></ns2:custom-data>')

SELECT
    Nodes.KeyC.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS KeyC
FROM @Data D
    CROSS APPLY XmlText.nodes('//keyc') AS Nodes(KeyC)
```

This outputs the following:

```
KeyC
-----------
123-ABC
8R
```